# Azure devops - Error : The value for PublishProfile is set to 'FileSystem'

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

My azure devops build started failing without any code or build changes.

The following error is thrown in the VisualStudio Build step

`Error : The value for PublishProfile is set to 'FileSystem', expected to find the file at '...\FileSystem.pubxml' but it could not be found.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/754048/error-the-value-for-publishprofile-is-set-to-files.html

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/issues/1276

I was able to work around it for now by changing my build host image from `windows-2019` to `vs2017-win2016`

So in my yaml

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016' #instead of window-2019
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could accept it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.